# How do i add values to a table from Python editor?

Tags: python, mysql-workbench, mysql-python

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
import mysql.connector
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',user='root',passwd='Alok1823!',database='kbc')
mycursor = mydb.cursor()
tempuser='tarran09'
mycursor.execute("insert into `kbc`.`player` ('username') values (tempuser) ")
```

How do I add values to a table from Python editor. The values are not direct values but rather stored in variables. I don't know what the contents of that variable are at any given moment. So how do add the value of these variables into one the tables of mySQL database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the variable is string then:

```
import mysql.connector
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',user='root',passwd='Alok1823!',database='kbc')
mycursor = mydb.cursor()
tempuser='tarran09'
mycursor.execute(f"insert into kbc.player (username) values ('{tempuser}')")
mydb.commit()
```

If you are using python version < 3.6, then

```
mycursor.execute("insert into kbc.player (username) values ('{}')".format(tempuser))
```

Comment: Thank You so much . The second syntax works for my system although i have python version 3.8